# Sql select object with all possible references to it

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables:

- fabric (id INTEGER, name TEXT)
- property (id INTEGER, name TEXT)

and a table that reference fabric properties to itself

- properties_to_fabric (fabric_id, prop_id, UNIQUE(fabric_id, prop_id))

Now I heen to come up with an SQL request which will select all the fabrics that have all of the existing properties.

What I have already tried is:

```
select 
    fabric_id, fabric_name 
from 
    properties_to_fabric 
where
    count(select * from properties_to_fabric where fabric_id = fabric_id) = count(select * from property);
```

Still, that doesn't work and I have no other ideas.

The database is SQLite3 if it is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select pf.fabric_id
from properties_to_fabric pf
group by pf.fabrid_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from properties);
```

Notes:

- If you need the name, you can `join` in the `fabrics` table.
- If the properties can be duplicated for a given fabric, then use `having count(distinct property_id) = . . .`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
select f.* from fabric f
where not exists (
  select 1 from property p
  where (f.id, p.id) not in (select fabric_id, prop_id from properties_to_fabric)
)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9KQUppNfUe2XMbNNihyHo7/0).